# I'm having trouble catching errors for this function

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm getting errors on the eight line "extra argument 'error'in call. Any suggestions?

@IBAction func loadFollowers(sender: AnyObject)
    {

```
    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json", parameters: ["user_id":Twitter.sharedInstance().session()!.userID], error: nil), completion:
        {(response:NSURLResponse?, data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        var dic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
        var friends = dic["ids"] as! NSArray
        self.following = friends

            Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json", parameters: ["user_id":Twitter.sharedInstance().session()!.userID], error: nil), completion: {(resonse:NSURLResponse?,data:NSData?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

            var dic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            var followers = dic["ids"] as! NSArray
            self.followers = followers
            for id in self.following {
                if !self.followers.containsObject(id)
                {
                    var st = id as! NSNumber
                    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadUserWithID(st.stringValue, completion: {(user:TWTRUser?,error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        self.results.addObject(user!)
                        //self.tableView.reloadData()
                        print("done")
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    })}
```

Comment: plz point out the error line in your code.

Comment: var dic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

Comment: you should use swift do try catch construct

Comment: "extra argument 'error'in call

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I modified the code as thus:

Comment: I modified it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C this used to be possible, now you have to do something like this:

```
do{
  let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
}catch let error{
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Same error.

Comment: @DavidiTokuta did you remove the `error:` parameter ?

Comment: by the way you have that line in line 3 and in line 9 in your code, so make sure you replace both of those.

Comment: You mean the 'error: error' ?

Comment: Yes, remove the whole 'error: error' from those lines. The reason you can do that is because the error parameter has been removed from the parameter list of the method call in Swift in favor of exception handling.

Comment: Great insight. Thanks a lot. I've got this other challenge with a Twitter app I'm building. I'm having some difficulty with the API calls. Can you help?

Comment: Sure, how do you want me to help ? you can either open a new question and link it here or if you want to contact me differently you can do that too...

Comment: Contacting you directly would be good. How do we proceed?

Comment: Are you good with JSON?

Comment: Sure, I'll set up a temporary email address and let you know when I'm home

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks!!

Comment: I set up an outlook account for Skype, you can find me by searching for `the__critic@outlook.com` I guess ? Drop me a message and let's see if that works!

Comment: Great stuff. Will do now.